# Google analytics collect parameter "a"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I captured a hit that i am sending to Universal Analytics.

/collect?v=1&_v=j31**&a=1233968061**&t=item&cu=SEK&_s=3&dl=siteaddress&de=UTF-8&dt=online shop&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1200&vp=1903x1065&je=1&jid=&cid=97152128.1418127174&tid=UA-Test-1&gtm=GTM-Test&cm1=desktop&z=1167078446
(is just a part of it)

Does anyone know what the "a" parameter represents? I could not find anything in the [Protocol Parameter Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) about it.

Comment: If it was timestamp, it'd be "Sat, 07 Feb 2009 01:54:21 +0100". Not sure if you can make any sense of that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'a' parameter is a random number generated and used to link Google Analytics to Google Adsense.  It is the equivalent of utmhid used in Google Analytics classic version.

[the reference doc for the classic version is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview?hl=en]

My source is the Google Analytics team directly as my company, DMPG.co.uk is a certified partner.

I wrote the cheatography sheet at http://www.cheatography.com/dmpg-tom/cheat-sheets/google-universal-analytics-url-collect-parameters/ and have now updated it with this information.

ps. sorry for being nearly a year late to the party on this one!