# Parameter "a" in google analytics

Tags: api, google-analytics

The string below was sent to google analytics when the user clicks on a button:

"v=1&_v=j31&a=214989120&t=event&_s=2&dl=http%3A%2F%2FMyServer.amazonaws.com%2Fga.html&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1920x
895&je=1&fl=16.0%20r0&ec=button&ea=click&el=nav-buttons&_u=eCCAAEQFI~&jid=&cid=1
528855396.1420545392&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&z=1765240355"

In the following url, there are parameters explanations:
"https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters"

But i didn't find any explanations to parameter "a" (In my example: a=214989120).

Does anybody know what is the explanations of "a"?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google analytics collect parameter "a"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420838/google-analytics-collect-parameter-a)

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Chrome Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) (by the GA team) which provided an answer to this:

```
a=AdSenseId
```